SpotifyAPI Get Recommendations Endpoint has been Deprecated
I'm building an application that is utilizing SpotifyAPI. One of the features I'm trying to implement is a search bar where users can search for their favourite tracks, but before even typing anything, I would want to provide users with some recommendations. While a "Search for Item" endpoint is working, the aforementioned "Get Recommendations" has been deprecated.
I'm looking for a similar funtionality, I couldn't think of one myself. Is there any way to get such recommendations without this endpoint?

I'm using the last.fm API to get recommendations: https://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getSimilar
